# Is it possible to livestream the screen of an iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, streaming

I have been looking for a way to livestream the screen of my iPad to Discord or some similar service so friends can watch but I haven't been able to find any clear info if this kind of thing is even possible, let alone which apps support it. Discord and Twitch seem to not support it in their apps at least.

I know Airplay is for streaming to TVs but this doesn't seem to be useful for me. Is this possible to do? My first preference would be streaming to Discord but alternatives would be good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Engage screen recording and you will see which apps allow you to stream from that app. Also, Airplay to an AppleTV or video out often can be sent to an HDMI capture card.

To try this you could use Zoom or WebEx or TeamViewer or Microsoft Teams. We pay for and use the last two at work widely, but I believe all of them let you try and use the app for non-commercial uses after registration.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207935

Also, the squirrels are awesome. Check out if you broadcast from a computer and share your iPad to it. Amazing things are possible for sharing now from iOS 14.

Comment: Ah I see that long pressing the screen recording button pops out a list of apps and discord is in the list. I'll have to give this a shot soon to test it out. I was just tapping the icon which didn't provide any way to stream